# memcpy and _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, char, memcpy

I have problem with memcpy in my for loop - I need trasform string to *char:

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
    char* Bchar = new char[Bi[i].length()+1];
    ZeroMemory(Bchar,Bi[i].length());
    memcpy(Bchar, Bi[i].c_str(), Bi[i].length()); //Exception on this row
    ...
    delete [] Bchar; 
}
```

There is link with the [exception](http://postimg.org/image/i2opzlvnh/)

Comment: That `ZeroMemory` is an utter waste of CPU cycles, since you're about to blast over *every* `char` of the very data you just zeroed. Secondly, your `memcpy` cannot be the line that is faulting if the size is as you describe *and* `B[i]` is a valid object (the latter being *very* important). It may be the *next* line that faults, as you never terminate your string so any code that relies on said-termination will utterly puke, or `B[i]` may not be valid.

Comment: Based on various comments, I suspect that additional problems might lie in the `...` section of code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not zero-terminating your string into the newly-created `Bchar` buffer. Depending on what you do with the `Bchar` buffer after you copy into it, you are quite likely accessing past the end of the buffer.

Instead of ZeroMemory/memcpy, simply use strcpy (or strcpy_s).

Comment: I try `strcpy_s(Bchar,Bi[i].length(),Bi[i].c_str());` and it is the same problem

Comment: Actually, it should be `Bi[i].length()+1`.

Comment: (The middle argument is the size of the destination buffer.)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
char* Bchar = new char[Bi[i].length()+1];
ZeroMemory(Bchar,Bi[i].length());
```

will not zero the last byte. And you do not copy in that byte in the subsequent `memcpy`.

Instead of `ZeroMemory` just use standard C++,

```
char* Bchar = new char[ Bi[i].length()+1 ]();
```

However, while that fixes the problem, why not just use a `std::vector` and let *it* manage the memory?

```
string const& s = Bi[i];
vector<char>  Bchar( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

As a general rule, treat any direct use of `new` and `delete` as an odour of ungoodness.

Comment: This solution fixed my problem but I need use the function from library TomLibMath - `mp_read_radix(mp_int *a, const char *str, int radix)` => i need the datatype char *Bchar

Comment: @user3077025 You get the data type `const char*` from `c_str()`! Like this `mp_read_radix(..., Bi[i].c_str(), ...);`. You're trying far too hard, you don't need to copy to a new string, you can use the one you've already got.

Comment: john: mp_read_radix(..., Bi[i].c_str(), ...); => there is the same problem